# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition user allow doesn't fire success or fail on first try

Tags: javascript, html

I have had this weird problem with the geolocation api. Currently I notice it in chrome but I think it happens in other browsers too.

The problem is that when I use getCurrentPosition for the first time the browsers allow button comes up. If I just wait for an extended period of time say 30 seconds and then press allow. No success of fail callback is fired.

Here is the code I am using

```
if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(_position) {
        console.log("success"); 
        console.log(_position);
    }, 
    function(_error) { 
        console.log("failed"); 
        console.log(_error); 
    }, {timeout: 5000});
}else{
    console.log("not supported");
}
```

I've also tried with {maximumAge: 60000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true}

The geolocation works the second time trough if the user has allowed it. Just the first time if they take too long to press the allow button no callback is fired.

I thought it might be that if they dont press allow within the timeout time then this error occurs but it seems not to be the case.

When I try it all by itself http://jsfiddle.net/CHEVs/ it works every time. All I can think is that It cant find the callback. What sort of situation would cause that to happen?

EDIT:

I just isolated when the error occurs. Managed to get it to happen in the jsfiddle. Go to your settings in chrome, clear the location permissions for jsfiddle. Close your browser and load up the jsfiddle again. Click getlocation wait for a little bit (don't think it matters how long) and then click allow. Nothing will happen.

Now go back and remove the permission for jsfiddle but this time dont close the browser. Click geolocation, wait then allow and it works. Seems to not work on the first time.